# How to tell Excel not to evaluate a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to tell Excel not to evaluate a cell as a formula?

Example cell entry: `-A23`

Excel wants to evaluate this as reference to a cell. But the data I am working with has another semantics and is no reference to a cell. How to tell Excel to leave these entries as they are?

Answer (score 26):

An alternate to what [mehow said](https://superuser.com/a/641271/94931) (if you have only a few instances like this), you can prepend a single quote:

```
'-A23
```

Putting this in a cell will appear as `-A23`.

Comment: The other similar option is the face formula: put in `="-A23"`. Generally not as useful but occasionally worth knowing at least.

Comment: @Chris Yup, quotes turns things into text in a formula.

Answer (score 12):

Format the cell as `Text`

Right-click the cell and select `Format Cells`

[image: 1]

then in pop-up window select formatting as `Text`

[image]

Now, enter anything you like in that cell

example (*look at the formula bar*)

[image]

Comment: and change font color to white?

Comment: @barlop I am sorry, do you want to change the font color to white?

Comment: no dude. this is the questioner's question, so one might ask, why might the questioner want the color to be white(i.e. effectively somewhat hidden) - that is what I was suggesting. Perhaps he wants the "formula" to be there  not to display in the cell e.g. not to display when he prints it and not to display in the grid, but there for him to see, so to display in the bar when he selects the cell, then he might want to change font color to white. because white text on a white background, i.e. on a white background grid in the cell, makes the white contents of the cell invisible.

Comment: @barlop I'm not sure where you got the idea that the OP wanted 'white'... "leave these entries as they are?" means display as `-A23` and not let excel turn it into `=-A23` as far as I see (which is excel's behaviour if you try it).

Comment: @barlop I'm sorry I think you must have misunderstood the question. I agree with the above Jerry's comment